# Plotting data from json file with different date format

Tags: json, parsing, datetime, d3.js, svg

I am using graph1.json file which is as given. The createdOn date in stored as date time value. The graph is plotted but at wrong values of createdOn. How to parse the date for plotting the graph.

```
{
    "Vitals": [
        {
            "createdOn": "2015-08-01 23:35:15.652",
            "read": "1",
            "ews": 3,
            "vitalVal": 78
        },
        {
            "createdOn": "2015-08-01 22:35:15.652",
            "read": "1",
            "ews": 2,
            "vitalVal": 82
        },
        {
            "createdOn": "2015-08-01 21:35:15.652",
            "read": "1",
            "ews": 2,
            "vitalVal": 80
        },
        {
            "createdOn": "2015-08-01 21:25:15.652",
            "read": "1",
            "ews": 4,
            "vitalVal": 101
        },
        {
            "createdOn": "2015-08-01 21:15:15.652",
            "read": "1",
            "ews": 0,
            "vitalVal": 100
        },
        {
            "createdOn": "2015-08-01 21:05:15.652",
            "read": "1",
            "ews": 1,
            "vitalVal": 85
        },
        {
            "createdOn": "2015-08-01 20:59:15.652",
            "read": "1",
            "ews": 0,
            "vitalVal": 91
        },
        {
            "createdOn": "2015-07-27 12:58:15.652",
            "read": "1",
            "ews": 0,
            "vitalVal": 96
        },
        {
            "createdOn": "2015-07-27 12:57:15.652",
            "read": "1",
            "ews": 0,
            "vitalVal": 94
        }
    ],
"unit": "mg"
}
```

My controller is

```
.controller('ChartCtrl', ['$scope','$http', function ($scope,$http) {

}])
.directive('linearChart', ['$http',function ($http) {
    return {
        restrict: 'EA',

        link: function (scope, elem, attrs) {
           var req = {
        method: 'GET',
        url: 'js/modules/myvitals/graph1.json',
        headers: {
        'Content-Type': "application/json"
        },
        data: {
            "userName":'userName'
            ,"password":'password'
          }
        }; 

        $http(req).then(function(response){
          //console.log(response.data);
         scope.data = response.data.SPO2;
          var data = scope.data;

            var margin = {
                top: 40,
                right: 20,
                bottom: 30,
                left: 50 
            },
            width = 365 - margin.left - margin.right,
            height = 300 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

            // Parse the date / time
            var parseDate = d3.time.format("%d-%b-%y").parse;
            console.log("Date parsed:"+parseDate);
            // Set the ranges
            var x = d3.time.scale().range([0, width]);
            var y = d3.scale.linear().range([height, 0]);

            // Define the axes
            var xAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(x)
                .orient("bottom").ticks(5).tickFormat(d3.time.format("%d"));

            var yAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(y)
                .orient("left").ticks(5);

            // Define the line1
            var valueline1 = d3.svg.line()
                .x(function (d) {
                 return x(new Date(d.createdOn));
               // return x(d.date);
            })
                .y(function (d) {
                return y(d.vitalVal);
            });


            // Adds the svg canvas
            var svg = d3.select("svg")
                .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
                .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
                .append("g")
                .attr("transform",
                "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

            // Scale the range of the data
            x.domain(d3.extent(data, function (d) {
                return new Date(d.createdOn);
            }));
            y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function (d) {
                return d.vitalVal;
            })]);

            // Add the valueline1 path.
            svg.append("path")
                .attr("class", "line")
                //.attr("id", "valueline1")      //add id to path for hide/show
                .attr("d", valueline1(data));

            //text label for y axis
            svg.append("text")
                .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
                .attr("y", 0 - margin.left)
                .attr("x", 0 - (height / 2))
                .attr("dy", "1em")
                .style("text-anchor", "middle")
                .attr("class", "ylabel")
                .text("Measurement (bpm)");

            // text label for the x axis
            svg.append("text")      
                    .attr("x", width/2 )
                    .attr("y", height +30)
                    .style("text-anchor", "middle")
                    .attr("class", "xlabel")
                    .text("Date");  

            // Add the scatterplot for line1
            svg.selectAll("dot")
                .data(data)
                .enter().append("circle")
                .attr("r", 4.5)
               // .attr("class", "valueline1")    //add class to each dot
                .style("fill", function (d) {
                if (d.ews == 0) return "green";
                if (d.ews == 1) return "yellow";
                if (d.ews == 2) return "orange";
                if (d.ews == 3) return "red";
            })
                .attr("cx", function (d) {
                  return x(new Date(d.createdOn));
                //return x(parseDate(d.createdOn));
            })
                .attr("cy", function (d) {
                return y(d.vitalVal);
            }) .on("mouseover", function () {
                return d3.select("#mytooltip").style("visibility", "visible"); //making the tooltip visible
            })
                .on("mousemove", function (d) {
               // console.log()
                d3.select("#mytooltip").style("top", (d3.mouse(this)[1] + 12) + "px").style("left", (d3.mouse(this)[0] + 10) + "px");
                d3.select("#mytooltip").select("#txvalue").text(function () {
                    return d.createdOn; //setting the date values to tooltip
                });
                d3.select("#mytooltip").select("#tyvalue").text(function () {
                    return d.vitalVal; //setting the date values to tooltip
                });
                return;
            })
                .on("mouseout", function () {
                return d3.select("#mytooltip").style("visibility", "hidden"); //hidding the tooltip
            });     


            // Add the X Axis
            svg.append("g")
                .attr("class", "x axis")
                .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
                .call(xAxis);

            // Add the Y Axis
            svg.append("g")
                .attr("class", "y axis")
                .call(yAxis);
// console.log(resposneData);
        }, function(error){
          console.log(error);

        });


        }
    };
}])
```

And I am rendering svg in html file

```
<div ng-controller="ChartCtrl"> 
            <svg linear-chart></svg>

            <div class="mytool" id="mytooltip">
              <div id="tyvalue"></div>
              <div id="txvalue"></div>
            </div>

</div>
```

Comment: question is not clear you are already handling teh date well  new Date(d.createdOn) ...where is teh problem.

Comment: I want the time in the format 10.00 AM, 12.30 PM etc.on tooltip

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do somthing like this in you tool tip

```
d3.select("#mytooltip").select("#ttdate").text(function () {
                    var timeFormat = d3.time.format('%I:%M %p');//to show time  in  10.00 AM, 12.30 PM
                    return timeFormat(new Date(d.date)); //setting the time values to tooltip
                });
                d3.select("#mytooltip").select("#ttclose").text(function () {
                    return d.close; //setting the date values to tooltip
                });
```

This is very good tutorial for d3 date formats http://bl.ocks.org/zanarmstrong/ca0adb7e426c12c06a95

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks, But, I am getting 10:NaN AM. Why %M not getting recognized?

Comment: Here is a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/cyril123/kyjdu7ra/28/ I think may be the json data you using is not correct.Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks, accepted. How to display the "unit" parameter from json in tooltip  along with Y axis value?

Comment: Hey I think you forgot to accept...this is how you can accept ana nswer http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23138/how-to-accept-the-answer-on-stack-overflow
Regarding your question of unit i sry i dont understand what you mean by unit here

Comment: Check my json file, last parameter is "unit". How to display the "unit" parameter from json in tooltip along with Y axis value?

Comment: you can do something like this return d.vitalVal + "( "+scope.data.unit + " )"; http://jsfiddle.net/cyril123/kyjdu7ra/29/

Comment: Say, if we have 2 more parameters in json "min":60,  "max":130 in json file after unit parameter. How to draw two horizontal lines and the area in between them shaded with gray color?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94595/discussion-between-cyril-and-wini).